# Nginx Map Regex

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to return a 415 error when the content_type is not application/json using Nginx which means I need to allow all traffic which is of content_type application/json using maps I have achieved the below

```
map $content_type $ct_check{
"application/json" 'pass';
~*(.*)'failed';
default      'pass';
```

However my end customers sends multiple content type like application/json;charset-utf8 something like this so I need to have a regex to allow all the content_types starting with application/json tried multiple combinations but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if `$content_type` begins with `application/json`, use a regular expression containing the "start of string anchor" (`^`).

For example:

```
~*^application/json  pass;
```

Place this regular expression above your `~*(.*) 'failed';` statement, as regular expressions are evaluated in order.

Comment: is there any regex that can be used to capture this application/json even if it resides at the middle something like this 
```
charset=utf8;application/json
```
matching the string anywhere

Comment: Use: `~*application/json  pass;`